# Crash EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) unity + vuforia + ios

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia, ios8.3

This is my first post.Does anyone know what error of this code? I use unity 4.6.5 with vuforia plugin 4 and xcode 6.2.  Apple center reject my app because iPhone 4S running iOS 8.3-iPhone 5C running iOS 8.3- iPhone 5S running iOS 8.3- iPhone 6 running iOS 8.3-iPhone 6 Plus
running iOS 8.3. Thank you for your answer.

> {"app_name":"miskokaiarbook","app_version":"1.0.3","bundleID":"com.misbook.miskokaiarbook","adam_id":0,"os_version":"iPhone
>
> > OS 8.3
> >     (12F70)","slice_uuid":"98a7d81f-6097-3825-ad55-85b2098f17dd","share_with_app_devs":false,"build_version":"1.0.3","is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","name":"miskokaiarbook"}
> >     Incident Identifier: E442A51C-4D54-4B99-BC44-27DA192FFA7B
> >     CrashReporter Key:   b332d3ccaec275d0d59a00e836cbf0b06f1574b6 Hardware
> >     Model:      iPhone7,2 Process:             miskokaiarbook [574] Path: 
> >     /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/518A5BD5-E9B2-4609-8652-2991B72446F1/miskokaiarbook.app/miskokaiarbook
> >     Identifier:          com.misbook.miskokaiarbook Version:
> >     1.0.3 (1.0.3) Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native) Parent Process:      launchd.development [1]
> >
> > Date/Time:           2015-06-08 06:39:19.319 -0700 Launch Time:
> >     2015-06-08 06:39:19.102 -0700 OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
> >     UDID:                7eaed071d28a51bcfeb2177974ba042b38abff24 Report
> >     Version:      105
> >
> > Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
> >     0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Triggered by Thread:  0
> >
> > Filtered syslog: 2015-06-08 06:39:19.245 miskokaiarbook[574]:
> >      -> registered mono modules 0x101190720 2015-06-08
> >     06:39:19.254 miskokaiarbook[574]:  assertion failed: 12F70:
> >     libxpc.dylib + 71768 [B870B51D-AA85-3686-A7D9-ACD48C5FE153]: 0x7d
> >
> > Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
> >     Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000019515f270
> >     0x195144000 + 111216 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >         0x00000001951fd16c 0x1951f8000 + 20844 2   libsystem_c.dylib
> >         0x00000001950d6b14 0x195074000 + 404244 3   miskokaiarbook
> >         0x000000010046d628 0x10000c000 + 4593192 4   miskokaiarbook
> >         0x000000010046d0b0 0x10000c000 + 4591792 5   miskokaiarbook
> >         0x00000001004463bc 0x10000c000 + 4432828 6   miskokaiarbook
> >         0x000000010001f3d0 0x10000c000 + 78800 7   UIKit
> >         0x0000000187b5f18c 0x187adc000 + 536972 8   UIKit
> >         0x0000000187d76850 0x187adc000 + 2730064 9   UIKit
> >         0x0000000187d79204 0x187adc000 + 2740740 10  UIKit
> >         0x0000000187d77774 0x187adc000 + 2733940 11  FrontBoardServices
> >         0x000000018b9953c4 0x18b97c000 + 103364 12  CoreFoundation
> >         0x0000000183064278 0x182f84000 + 918136 13  CoreFoundation
> >         0x0000000183063380 0x182f84000 + 914304 14  CoreFoundation
> >         0x00000001830619a4 0x182f84000 + 907684 15  CoreFoundation
> >         0x0000000182f8d2d0 0x182f84000 + 37584 16  UIKit
> >         0x0000000187b58438 0x187adc000 + 508984 17  UIKit
> >         0x0000000187b52fa8 0x187adc000 + 487336 18  miskokaiarbook
> >         0x0000000100010bcc 0x10000c000 + 19404 19  libdyld.dylib
> >         0x0000000195046a04 0x195044000 + 10756
> >
> > Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager Thread
> >     1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x0000000195144c24 0x195144000 +
> >     3108 1   libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000195029e6c 0x195018000
> >     + 73324 2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019501b998 0x195018000 + 14744
> >
> > Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: FBSSerialQueue Thread 2: 0
> >     libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195144e48 0x195144000 + 3656 1
> >     libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195027f3c 0x195018000 + 65340
> >     2   FrontBoardServices              0x000000018b995384 0x18b97c000 +
> >     103300 3   libdispatch.dylib                0x0000000195019990
> >     0x195018000 + 6544 4   libdispatch.dylib
> >         0x0000000195019950 0x195018000 + 6480 5   libdispatch.dylib
> >         0x00000001950240a0 0x195018000 + 49312 6   libdispatch.dylib
> >         0x000000019501ca58 0x195018000 + 19032 7   libdispatch.dylib
> >         0x0000000195026314 0x195018000 + 58132 8   libdispatch.dylib
> >         0x0000000195027c48 0x195018000 + 64584 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >         0x00000001951f9228 0x1951f8000 + 4648 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >         0x00000001951f8eec 0x1951f8000 + 3820
> >
> > Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000019515fc78
> >     0x195144000 + 113784 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >         0x00000001951f92d8 0x1951f8000 + 4824 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >         0x00000001951f8eec 0x1951f8000 + 3820
> >
> > Thread 4 name:  GC Finalizer Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
> >         0x000000019515f078 0x195144000 + 110712 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >         0x00000001951faf28 0x1951f8000 + 12072 2   miskokaiarbook
> >         0x0000000100b21160 0x10000c000 + 11620704 3   miskokaiarbook
> >         0x0000000100afd998 0x10000c000 + 11475352 4   miskokaiarbook
> >         0x0000000100b1bc80 0x10000c000 + 11598976 5   miskokaiarbook
> >         0x0000000100b24ba0 0x10000c000 + 11635616 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >         0x00000001951fbdc4 0x1951f8000 + 15812 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >         0x00000001951fbd20 0x1951f8000 + 15648 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >         0x00000001951f8ef4 0x1951f8000 + 3828
> >
> > Thread 5: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000019515fc78
> >     0x195144000 + 113784 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >         0x00000001951f92d8 0x1951f8000 + 4824 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >         0x00000001951f8eec 0x1951f8000 + 3820
> >
> > Thread 6: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000019515fc78
> >     0x195144000 + 113784 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >         0x00000001951f92d8 0x1951f8000 + 4824 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >         0x00000001951f8eec 0x1951f8000 + 3820
> >
> > Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
> >         x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000016fdf1cec
> >         x4: 0x000000016fdf1ce8   x5: 0x000000000000001d   x6: 0x0000000000000067   x7: 0x00000000000008c0
> >         x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000018    x12: 0x0000000000000001
> >     x13: 0x0000000000062aa8  x14: 0x0000000000000015  x15:
> >     0x0000000000000000    x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000
> >     x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006    x20:
> >     0x000000019903f310  x21: 0x0000000198fe9030  x22: 0x0000000000000002 
> >     x23: 0x000000010119baa8    x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25:
> >     0x00000001882c4e6e  x26: 0x00000001882c9ac0  x27: 0x00000000000000b0
> >     x28: 0x000000013ee6f5b0  fp: 0x000000016fdf1d40   lr:
> >     0x00000001951fd170
> >         sp: 0x000000016fdf1d20   pc: 0x000000019515f270 cpsr: 0x00000000

Comment: Please show us your Unity Export settings. And always make sure you're using the latest Vuforia and Unity (Currently Unity 5 Vuforia 4.2)

Comment: [Here is my Setting](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/11356166_10152808492120981_670270249_n.jpg?oh=c1d4ff9ea8aafc15cf944db2514fa22e&oe=557A48EC&__gda__=1434089304_ff0ae39fb4ccfc92dc8a8986dede2086)

Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, from your Question, it looks like you've checked on `Multithreading`in your Build Settings? Disable that, I really doubt you'll have the need to use it.

From the picture in your comment, you seem to have used Architecture - `Universal`. Instead, change that to `ARMv7` and as per your question you said you're targeting `iOS 8.3`, yet your Target SDK in Build settings is only `iOS 7'.

Your target SDK must always align with the latest SDK available at that moment. I don't think Unity 4.6 will have `iOS 8` so in that case you might have to update your Unity 5. If it has the option of iOS 8 on your current version, then you HAVE to make sure it targets the latest SDK.

Similarly make sure you've got got your Build Settings on xCode perfectly to align with your Developer certificates and make sure the settings there are the same as it is on your Build settings in Unity.

It should work for sure! All the best!

Comment: Problem solve,I upgrade osx to 10.10,xcode to 6.3.
Thank you.

Comment: My reputation is too low.